# How can I modify the loop from a plugin without wiping out other filters?

Tags: loop, taxonomy

I am trying to modify `the_loop` output from a plugin. I've looked into `pre_get_posts`, which definitely works, but I need to filter the loop by a custom taxonomy. I can do this with `$query->set('tax_query',$my_tax_new_query)`, but the problem is this overrides any previous taxonomy queries that may have been set. It applies my query **INSTEAD** of the former query instead of **IN ADDITION TO IT**. How can I apply an additional taxonomy filter to the loop without wiping out the previous query?

EDIT:

For example:

```
function myplugin_filter_the_loop($query) {

    $taxonomy = 'hobbies';
    $exclude_terms = array('biking','swimming','horsebackriding');

    $query->set('tax_query',$exclude_terms)

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','myplugin_filter_the_loop');
```

This works, but it will REPLACE any previously defined `tax_query` on the loop.

EDIT2:

Alternative using `posts_where`:

```
function myplugin_filter_the_loop($where) {

    $relationship_ids = array(97,98,99);

    foreach ( $relationship_ids as $id ) :

        $where .= " AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ($id)"

    endforeach;

}
add_filter('posts_where','myplugin_filter_the_loop');
```

For this to work, I'd just need to get the corresponding relationship id by term_id or slug, etc.

Comment: One alternative I've looked into is appending the `posts_where` filter and adding ` AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (99) ) )` where 99 refers to my taxonomy term in `wp_term_relationships` --- However I can't figure out how to arrive at 99 without manually coding it. Is this a good alternative? How can I get this id from a corresponding term_id or slug?

Comment: Post your callback for the `pre_get_posts` hook, please. It should be a relatively simple matter of merging data.

Comment: What is the **specific context** in which you need to modify the Loop? The main loop on *every* page, or only in certain contexts?

Comment: Yep, every page, whether the main loop or not.

Comment: Ok, so I ended up going with the `posts_where` filter in EDIT2 above. I was able to get the term ids using `$term->term_taxonomy_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );` to get the existing tax_query, modify it by adding your changes, then use `$query->set( 'tax_query', new_$tax_query` ); to put the whole thing back.

Comment: So `$query->get` comes back NULL, but I was able to get the original `tax_query` with `get_query_var('tax_query')`. However, now I need to wrap it in another tax_query. I haven't been able to get a nested tax_query to work. Can this be done/What is the proper format? For example, I want `'tax_query' = array('relation'=>'AND', array('taxonomy'=>'exclude', 'field'=>'id', 'terms'=>array(97, 98, 99), array('relation'='OR', array(...), array(...))`

Comment: You can't have two separate things with different relations like that. That isn't how tax_query works.